# just-audio-web Error: NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: flutter, dart, autoplay, autostart, just-audio

It's acting like an autoplay issue.
The error received is:
"NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."

Additionaly when I load a playlist and press Next, it also doesn't start playing automatically.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, that's two questions. Best to ask the first question and get an answer for that. See if that helps you, and if not, you can then ask a second question.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow autoplay of audio: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

I got around the issue by putting a button in flutter and then playing the audio using just-audio-web when onPressed